How is $2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}-2$ equal to $(\sqrt{3} -\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)$?
I was working on a problem on how to prove that $\tan\frac{\pi}{24} =(\sqrt{3} -\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)$.
The solution I had obtained is $\tan\frac{\pi}{24}=2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}-2$.

How is $2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}-2$ equal to $(\sqrt{3} -\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)$ ?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Using an Approach0 search, there's the closely related AoPS thread problem in trig #4, where its Post #$6$ uses the $\tan 2x$ identity to solve the problem, as you suggested could be done.

@Community:  it seems to me that exactly what OP is asking for is a demonstration that $(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)(\sqrt2-1)=2\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}-\sqrt3-2$

Your result was false. The true value is $$\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}}$$

@Piquito:  actually your expression has the same value as OP's

@J.W. Tanner:  It's weird because in Desmos it gave me different values ​​although now it gives me the same values ​​(I must have made a mistake when writing the expressions). Thanks. Best regards.

Observe:
$$(\sqrt{3} -\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)=\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}-2$$
$$2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{3})^2}$$
Alternatively (since both expressions are positive):
$$\left(2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)^2=4(2+\sqrt{3})=8+4\sqrt{3}$$
$$(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2})^2=8+2\sqrt{12}=8+4\sqrt{3}$$

The alternative approach cuts to the heart of the matter. +1
